# Android system application update restoring to default after reboot

Tags: android

I've written a system application which is included in my system image. When I run an update with the same package name and signature its working fine, meaning I'm able to see the version name change to 0.0.2 but when i reboot the system it restore to default.

In the System default app in manifest file i have set:

```
android:versionCode="0"
android:versionName="0.0.1"
```

And in the Update app i have set:

```
android:versionCode="0" 
android:versionName="0.0.2" // no other change
```

Does anyone know why its not changing to 0.0.2?

Thanks,
GKapoor

Comment: Android generally will not consider 0 to 0 to be an upgrade. I have not attempted to play with apps in system images, though.

Comment: Thanks i will try with 0 to 1 and will let you know.

Comment: It's working with this change i.e. 0 to 1 :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed by changing version code from 0 to 1.